# Android Release error: Expected a color resource id (R.color.) but received an RGB integer

Tags: android, colors, r.java-file, expected-exception

I have an application in the market for a year. Last week, I have changed the source code of my app. When I wanted to build the release version Android Studio throws an Error:

"Error: Expected a color resource id (R.color.) but received an RGB integer [ResourceType]"

Color is only used in this part of code and I haven't made ​​any changes in this part:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            rlFlash.setBackground(new ColorDrawable
                    (Color.parseColor(("#86cc55"))));
        }
        else{
            rlFlash.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable
                    (Color.parseColor(("#86cc55"))));
        }
```

It is so strange that in the Debug version Android studio didn't throw any error and I can build the apk.

Do you know whats happen??

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Though it's too late, but this answer is for those who may still get this error while taking release build like me. Don't know if it's a solution or just workaround.

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
```

Use this at your method signature like below where you get the error.

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
public void aMethodWhereYouMayGetTheError(){
}
```

By using this you will be able to take release build without that error.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
rlFlash.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#86cc55"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have used the anotation @ColorRes in this method then remove that. The apk will be generated successfully.
Refer to [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24716905/6769497) to clarify further about the lint checks. The answer is quoted below:

> There are Java annotations to support these checks in your own code.
>   They can all be found in the android.support.annotations package:
>   IdRes  DrawableRes  LayoutRes  StringRes ColorRes &c  In this case,
>   for example, I could use:

```
private void mySetContentView(@LayoutRes int resourceId) {
    setContentView(resourceId); 
}
```

> and Android Studio will check that the provided resource id is indeed
>   for a layout. Moreover, these annotations are exported, so they can be
>   especially useful when designing a library.

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.